# How to have a displacement modifier vary it's shape within an array

Tags: modifiers, displacement

Total new on Blender cycles. I want to create a pyramid and for this I would like each stone to have a different displacement map. When I do one stone with the displacement map modifier it looks awesome, but when I put that into an array now all stone look the same. I tried using bump map with noise texture, and yes each stone have a different bump map, but it looks fake compare to the effect that I can get with a displacement modifier. Is there anyway to make the displacement modifier have a randomized texture so that each stone looks different, in its actual shape and geometry and not just in the bump map?
Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

### Displacement Modifier:

### Edit:

***As @Duarte Farrajota Ramos pointed out - for Array Modifier it's sufficient to just have Displace under Array without changing Texture Coordinates. Change is needed only for manually duplicated meshes.***

This one is very simple *(taken that you are using **Texture Type** other than **Image Texture**)*.

Just select **Texture Coordinates** as **Global** in **Displace Modifier**.

> Note: I've forgot to add **Array Modifier** in this example, remember to
>   add **Displace Modifier** **AFTER** **Array Modifier**.

For this example I've used **Texture Type** > **Distorted Noise**.

[image: displace]

### Micropolygon Displacement (experimental):

You can read how to use it here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Maiself/Micropolygon_Displacement or just search for tutorials on the internet, there are a lot of them.

[image: displace]

Comment: It would probably suffice to displace after arraying, by placing the *Displace* modifier lower in the stack than the *Array*

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yep, this one is true. I've made an edit for this. My bad. I've made manual copies and the Global Texture Coordinate is needed fot them, not for Array.